# How can I finish the workaround of having program look at libicu*60 when searching for libicu*50?

Tags: symbolic-link, shared-library

[Rewording first sentence as it created confusion]: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to run a proprietary program that was released this year.  The program was built with the intention that it would be run under Redhat.  When I start it in Ubuntu, I get the complaint:

> error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.50: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My machine has libicu*60 installed.  I read up on workarounds and one I found here suggested symbolic links so *50 looks at *60 since these two cannot be installed simultaneously and there could be dependencies I break by going backwards.  I created the links and made progress, but am now getting:

> symbol lookup error: /home/code/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined symbol: ucnv_getDefaultName_50

which is, I believe, related to my using the symbolic links.  This seems to be a variable in a program.  Is there any workaround for this?  I'm surprised that a 2020 version of a program would be looking for such an old version of this library, but perhaps Redhat ships with an older version??

Comment: As per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic support for 20.04 is limited. Please upgrade to a supported version, for until you do, this question is off topic

Comment: Well, I read the entire post and here are my observation. (1) The original post / question has NOT been edited as of yet (2) It is about some "proprietary program (2020 version)", and Ubuntu 18.04. (3) It does not mentions Ubuntu 20.04 at all. (4) The question may or may not be solvable but it's certainly not about Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.   I included the detail that the program is from 2020 as I was surprised it is looking for such an old version of libicu with a build from this year.  I think it confused matters.  I cleaned the first sentence up.  Yes, I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: One thing you could try (if you can locate an Ubuntu/Debian version of `libicudata.so.50`) placing it somewhere outside of the system library path, such as `$HOME/lib`, and then using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to locate it. But that *may* take you down a rabbithole of subordinate dependencies.